# Navigation Properties get overwritten when I update my Entity framework from database

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a table called **Matches** and a table called **Teams** in my database where my Matches table has two foreign key **HomeTeamID** and **AwayTeamID** link to Teams table.

When I generate edmx file I got **Team** and **Team1** in my Navigation Properties in my Matches class. I overwrote them to **HomeTeam** and **AwayTeam** in the design panel, and everything works fine.

But next time when I update my model from database, their names changed back to **Team** and **Team1**.

How can I solve this? 
Thank you in advance =)

Comment: You may consider moving to Entity Framework. Such things are easier there.

Answer (score 0):

Add real foreign keys to your DB.